# How can I modify a Python script to calculate the distance between an object and a pair of IR cameras?

Tags: python, function, camera, distance

I am an undergraduate student that recently took over a research project from my professor's previous assistant who graduated a couple weeks ago. The project she was working on involved the use of IR cameras to capture a thermal image of objects and finding where those objects were at their highest temperature. She uses two IR cameras set up perpendicularly to one another in an enclosed environment to get both a 'front' and a 'side' view of the object.

However, she was a computer science major while I am physics. I have taken all of one class in comp sci for coding in Python. One of the things my professor was hoping I could achieve early in the project was to fix a bit in her code where the objects go out of frame. The other girl showed me in the coding where she had it, and my task is to find out how to make the distance calculation able to change if the object being tested is not in the center of the box? Her central point was 12.5cm, which is referenced twice in the code (the code is in python script);

```
distance_back = (int(val_x) * 0.0264583333) + 12.5
distance_side = (int(val_2x) * 0.0264583333) + 12.5
```

Where `val_x` and `val_2x` are the position of the pixel in frame from the 'front' camera and 'side' camera, respectively, and 0.0264583333 is the length of each pixel.

I was told I could need to change the '12.5's into a function (or, likely, a pair of functions, one for each camera), and while I know how to make a function, how would I make it so that the function can calculate the distance between the object and the camera for the calculation?

The code I was given is working for what it does, I just don't have enough experience with coding to know what exactly I need to do to make it better in the way my professor and the ex-assistant want me to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question you posted is extremely broad and seems to be pretty involved with geometry as well as programming. I suggest you first solve the math portions (you can probably do this by yourself since you're a physics major, but you can also consult the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site) and then try to implement it yourself before posting here again. "Do it for me" questions are generally discouraged. For more details please read [ask].

Comment: That is a fair point, my apologies! I was thinking if I had the ability to find the distance first it would be easier to find the actual distance, but to be fair the basal distance would just go in the function code as a parameter, so. Apologies, again! I'll figure out the math part and then put up an edit for the question! And thank you! <3